# Jsp with MySql showing Column not found

Tags: mysql, jsp

When i click login from my previous page it shows the error and i have the table in my sql and the names are correct .. need a solution for this.

When i click login from my previous page it shows the error and i have the table in my sql and the names are correct .. need a solution for this.

Below is the code related to the issue:

```
<%-- 
   Document   : userLogged
   Created on : Mar 4, 2016, 11:55:53 PM
   Author     : Arun`enter code here`
--%>
<%//@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%//@page import="java.util.TimeZone"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%//@page import="java.util.Date" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexcss.css">    
     <title>Logged page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <center>
          <h1><b id="heading">Bus Recognition and Addressing using Web Services</b></h1>

                  <%
                      String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
                      String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
                      //session.putValue("uname", uname);
                      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                      java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mtc","root","root");
                      //Statement st=con.createStatement();
                      //ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select name,pass from reg where name=? and pass=?" );
                     PreparedStatement st= con.prepareStatement("select name,pass from reg where name=? and pass=?");
                     st.setString(1, uname);
                     st.setString(2, pass);
                     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();


                     if(rs.next())
                     {
                         out.println("welcome");
                         Statement stmt = null;
               stmt = con.createStatement();
               String query = "select * from bus";
               ResultSet rs1 = null;
               rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                          /*PreparedStatement st2= con.prepareStatement("select * from bus;");
                         ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery();*/
                         while(rs1.next()){
           %>
          <table  width="50%" cellpadding="3"  id="block" >
                       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Bus number</th>
               <th>Availability</th>
               <th>Terminal</th>

           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <%
                   String name = rs1.getString("bus_no");
                   int avail = rs1.getInt("avail");
                   int terminal = rs1.getInt("terminal");
               %>
               <td><%=name %></td>
               <td><%=avail %></td>
               <td><%=terminal %></td>
           </tr>               

           <%      
               }

                     }
                     else
                         out.println("Invalid login credentials");

                     /*Date date = new Date();
                      TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
                      date = cal.getTime();*/
                  %>

       </tbody>
           </table>
               </div>
           </center>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a little mistake happens nothing else and **solution is below**.

Comment: YEs!!what i learnt is that not to copy paste from previous statements ,, T_T forgot to change to rs1...

Answer (score 0):

> **Error in just a little Mistake in your code**

```
ResultSet rs1 = null;
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

> **change to**

```
ResultSet rs1 = null;
rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```